# SQL to Return Id Arguments of Records That Are Found not to Exist

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord

I have a query where by I'm working with an array of properties e.g. [1,2,3,4] etc. I need to check a table to see if a record with that id exists, I'm interested in the ones that don't exist rather than the ones that do.

At the moment I'm looping over the array in Ruby then making separate SELECT requests for each one. This works, but often the array is very long and it seems very inefficient making many separate requests.

I was wondering if there's a way to pass the whole array to Postgres and then Postgres hand me back all of the id's that don't exist.

Thanks,

Chris

Answer (score 1):

Okay figured it out:

```
SELECT *
FROM unnest(ARRAY[1,2,3,4,5]) as s
WHERE s NOT IN (SELECT id FROM my_table);
```

Comment: In version 8.4 or later it is generally better to use `NOT EXISTS` rather than `NOT IN`: `AS s(id) WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM my_table m WHERE m.id = s.id);`  This will usually optimize to a faster plan with large volumes, and Will probably not surprise you so much if you have a NULL in the array.

Comment: It might be cleaner to use `generate_series(1, 5) as s` instead of unnest....  It might perform better too.